# Java exception handling performance optimization

Tags: java, performance, exception, optimization

I'm trying to find the right way to set up the exception handling code for addressing performance hits..
here are some number i got.
Basically I want to set it up to to handle a  exception call to back end web services..
Any comments on whether one way gives better per formance than the other and why would be appreciated.
thank you..

## I’ve posted some times for three different coding structures in java

```
Try time Existing Code Structure throw same exception in catch block:12632
Try timeestimatedTimeTryThrowsChild Exception inCatchBlock: 1579
Try timeestimatedTimeTryReturnNullAfter Catch Block: 1579

Try time Existing Code Structure throw same exception in catch block:16580
Try timeestimatedTimeTryThrowsChild Exception inCatchBlock: 2368
Try timeestimatedTimeTryReturnNullAfter Catch Block: 4737


Try time Existing Code Structure throw same exception in catch block:29211
Try timeestimatedTimeTryThrowsChild Exception inCatchBlock: 3947
Try timeestimatedTimeTryReturnNullAfter Catch Block: 2369

Try time Existing Code Structure throw same exception in catch block:9869
Try timeestimatedTimeTryThrowsChild Exception inCatchBlock: 1974
Try timeestimatedTimeTryReturnNullAfter Catch Block: 1579


Try time Existing Code Structure throw same exception in catch block:13422
Try timeestimatedTimeTryThrowsChild Exception inCatchBlock: 1579
Try timeestimatedTimeTryReturnNullAfter Catch Block: 1579

Try time Existing Code Structure throw same exception in catch block:9474
Try timeestimatedTimeTryThrowsChild Exception inCatchBlock: 1579
Try timeestimatedTimeTryReturnNullAfter Catch Block: 1973

Try time Existing Code Structure throw same exception in catch block:5922
Try timeestimatedTimeTryThrowsChild Exception inCatchBlock: 789
Try timeestimatedTimeTryReturnNullAfter Catch Block: 789
```

```
public class Overhead {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "";

        long startTimeTry = System.nanoTime();
        tryTrimThrowSameException(testString);
        long estimatedTimeTry = System.nanoTime() - startTimeTry;

        long startTimeIf = System.nanoTime();
        ifTrim(testString);
        long estimatedTimeIf = System.nanoTime() - startTimeIf;

        long startTimeTryThrowsinCatchBlock = System.nanoTime();
        tryTrimThrowsChildExceptioninCatchBlock(testString);
        long estimatedTimeTryThrowsinCatchBlock = System.nanoTime() - startTimeTryThrowsinCatchBlock;

        long startTimeTryReturnNull = System.nanoTime();
        tryTrimReturnNull(testString);
        long estimatedTimeTryReturnNull = System.nanoTime() - startTimeTryReturnNull;



        System.out.println("Try time Existing Code Structure throw same exception in catch block:" + estimatedTimeTry);
        //System.out.println("If time:" + estimatedTimeIf);
        System.out.println("Try timeestimatedTimeTryThrowsChild Exception inCatchBlock: " + estimatedTimeTryThrowsinCatchBlock);
        System.out.println("Try timeestimatedTimeTryReturnNullAfter Catch Block: " + estimatedTimeTryReturnNull);

    }

    public static String tryTrimThrowSameException(String raw) {
        try {
            return raw.trim();
        }
        catch (java.lang.Exception e ) {

            //throw new java.lang.NullPointerException() ;

            System.out.println("throws an exception") ;
            throw e ;
        }
        //return null;
    }



    public static String tryTrimThrowsChildExceptioninCatchBlock(String raw) {
        try {
            return raw.trim();
        }
        catch (java.lang.Exception e ) {
            System.out.println("throws an exception") ;
            throw new java.lang.NullPointerException()  ;
            //throw e ;
        }
        //   return null;
    }



    public static String tryTrimReturnNull(String raw) {
        try {
            return raw.trim();
        }
        catch (java.lang.Exception e ) {

            //throw new java.lang.NullPointerException() ;

            System.out.println("throws an exception") ;
            //throw e ;
        }
        return null;
    }



    public static String ifTrim(String raw) {
        if (raw == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return raw.trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without looking at the performance: If you know that something can be `null` then check for it. It's called "exceptions" for a reason.

Comment: See: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: Is your question if by throwing a different exception than the current one if it incurs a performance penalty? Because I don't really understand your question

Comment: Check this article regarding correct micro-benchmarking in general and performance of exceptions handling in Java in particular: https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/